# Get Matrix of minimum coordinate distance to point set

Tags: matlab

I have a set of points or coordinates like {(3,3), (3,4), (4,5), ...} and want to build a matrix with the minimum distance to this point set. Let me illustrate using a runnable example:

```
width = 10;
height = 10;

% Get min distance to those points
pts = [3 3; 3 4; 3 5; 2 4];

sumSPts = length(pts);

% Helper to determine element coordinates
[cols, rows] = meshgrid(1:width, 1:height);
PtCoords = cat(3, rows, cols);

AllDistances = zeros(height, width,sumSPts);

% To get Roh_I of evry pt
for k = 1:sumSPts

    % Get coordinates of current Scribble Point
    currPt = pts(k,:);

    % Get Row and Col diffs
    RowDiff = PtCoords(:,:,1) - currPt(1);
    ColDiff = PtCoords(:,:,2) - currPt(2);

    AllDistances(:,:,k) = sqrt(RowDiff.^2 + ColDiff.^2);

end

MinDistances = min(AllDistances, [], 3);
```

This code runs perfectly fine but I have to deal with matrix sizes of about 700 milion entries (height = 700, width = 500, sumSPts = 2k) and this slows down the calculation. Is there a better algorithm to speed things up?

Comment: check the diff function - it might help you

Comment: If you have the image processing toolbox, look into [`bwdist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwdist.html). With 700 million points, any solution is going to be slow.

Comment: Actually, you don't have to deal with matrices with 700M entries. You can slice up your pts vector, keep the min of the slices and then take the global min. Would a processing time of ~20s be good for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you don't necessary have to put everything into a huge matrix and deal with gigantic matrices. You can :

**1. Slice the pts matrix into reasonably small slices (say of length 100)**

**2. Loop on the slices and calculate the `Mindistances` slice over these points**

**3. Take the global min**

---

```
tic

Mindistances=[];

width = 500;
height = 700;

Np=2000;

pts = [randi(width,Np,1) randi(height,Np,1)];

SliceSize=100;

[Xcoords,Ycoords]=meshgrid(1:width,1:height);


% Compute the minima for the slices from 1 to floor(Np/SliceSize)
for i=1:floor(Np/SliceSize)

    % Calculate indexes of the next slice
    SliceIndexes=((i-1)*SliceSize+1):i*SliceSize


    % Get the corresponding points and reshape them to a vector along the 3rd dim.
    Xpts=reshape(pts(SliceIndexes,1),1,1,[]);
    Ypts=reshape(pts(SliceIndexes,2),1,1,[]);

    % Do all the diffs between your coordinates and your points using bsxfun singleton expansion
    Xdiffs=bsxfun(@minus,Xcoords,Xpts);
    Ydiffs=bsxfun(@minus,Ycoords,Ypts);

    % Calculate all the distances of the slice in one call
    Alldistances=bsxfun(@hypot,Xdiffs,Ydiffs);

    % Concatenate the mindistances
    Mindistances=cat(3,Mindistances,min(Alldistances,[],3));


end

% Check if last slice needed
if mod(Np,SliceSize)~=0

    % Get the corresponding points and reshape them to a vector along the 3rd dim.
    Xpts=reshape(pts(floor(Np/SliceSize)*SliceSize+1:end,1),1,1,[]);
    Ypts=reshape(pts(floor(Np/SliceSize)*SliceSize+1:end,2),1,1,[]);

    % Do all the diffs between your coordinates and your points using bsxfun singleton expansion
    Xdiffs=bsxfun(@minus,Xcoords,Xpts);
    Ydiffs=bsxfun(@minus,Ycoords,Ypts);

    % Calculate all the distances of the slice in one call
    Alldistances=bsxfun(@hypot,Xdiffs,Ydiffs);

    % Concatenate the mindistances
    Mindistances=cat(3,Mindistances,min(Alldistances,[],3));

end

% Get global minimum
Mindistances=min(Mindistances,[],3);

toc
```

> Elapsed time is 9.830051 seconds.

### Note :

You'll not end up doing less calculations. But It will be a lot less intensive for your memory (700M doubles takes 45Go in memory), thus speeding up the process (With the help of vectorizing aswell)

---

### About [bsxfun](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) singleton expansion

One of the great strength of `bsxfun` is that you don't have to feed it matrices whose values are along the same dimensions.

**For example :**

Say I have two vectors `X` and `Y` defined as :

```
X=[1 2]; % row vector X
Y=[1;2]; % Column vector Y
```

And that I want a `2x2` matrix `Z` built as `Z(i,j)=X(i)+Y(j)` for `1<=i<=2 and 1<=j<=2`.

Suppose you don't know about the existence of `meshgrid` (The example is a bit too simple), then you'll have to do :

```
Xs=repmat(X,2,1);
Ys=repmat(Y,1,2);
Z=Xs+Ys;
```

While with `bsxfun` you can just do :

```
Z=bsxfun(@plus,X,Y);
```

To calculate the value of `Z(2,2)` for example, `bsxfun` will automatically fetch the second value of `X` and `Y` and compute. This has the advantage of saving a lot of memory space (No need to define `Xs` and `Ys` in this example) and being faster with big matrices.

### Bsxfun Vs Repmat

If you're interested with comparing the computational time between `bsxfun` and `repmat`, here are two **excellent** (word is not even strong enough) SO posts by *Divakar* :

[Comparing BSXFUN and REPMAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719674/comparing-bsxfun-and-repmat)

[BSXFUN on memory efficiency with relational operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29800560/bsxfun-on-memory-efficiency-with-relational-operations)

Comment: Thanks for your post! The solution does a pretty good job but fails when Np / SliceSize is not an integer (points get left out of the calculation). The "last" SliceIndexes with length(SliceIndexes) < Np/SliceSize is not calculated correctly. How good is the performance of "bsxfun(@minus,Xcoords,Xpts);" vs simply subtracting?

Comment: You're welcome! Of course for the last slice, a simple fix will seal the deal. About the substraction, `bsxfun` doesn't just do that, it also gets rid of a call to repmat by using singleton expansion. I'm editing my answer with the fix. I'm editing my answer with the changes and a little explanation of singleton expansion